# How to update scons build, when source file changes

Tags: scons, eiffel

I do not get the automated build to update the project with SCons. First I change something in the source files and the scons tells me:

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

How to update an automated build?

UPDATE 20170601:

leder@PC-LAP127:~/Source/Eiffel/PF_HP-mt$ scons --tree=prune project=pf_hp.ecf

```
+-.
  +-.sconf_temp
  +-SConstruct
  +-build
  | +-build/F_code-unix.tar
  | | +-pf_hp.ecf
  | | +-project.py
  | | +-/home/leder/Source/Eiffel/library/Eiffel-Loop/precomp/linux-x86-64/console-application.ecf
  | |   +-/home/leder/Source/Eiffel/library/Eiffel-Loop/precomp/console-application.ecf
  | +-build/linux-x86-64
  |   +-build/linux-x86-64/package
  |     +-build/linux-x86-64/package/bin
  |       +-build/linux-x86-64/package/bin/pf_hp
  |         +-[build/F_code-unix.tar]
  +-config.log
  +-pf_hp.ecf
  +-project.py
```

leder@PC-LAP127:~/Source/Eiffel/PF_HP-mt$ tree -L 2 .

```
.
├── build
│   ├── F_code-unix.tar
│   ├── linux-x86-64
│   └── version.txt
├── config.log
├── EIFGENs
│   └── classic
├── git_push.sh
├── input.txt
├── LICENSE.gpl
├── LIESMICH.txt
├── pf_hp.ecf
├── pf_hp.ecf.old
├── pf_hp.pecf
├── project.py
├── project.pyc
├── README.txt
├── SConstruct
├── source
│   ├── application_root.e
│   ├── build_info.e
│   ├── folding
│   ├── notes
│   ├── sub-applications
│   └── testing
└── test.sh

9 directories, 17 files
```

leder@PC-LAP127:~/Source/Eiffel/PF_HP-mt$ less SConstruct

```
import eiffel_loop.eiffel.SConstruct
SConstruct (END)
```

UPDATE_20170601, eiffel_loop.eiffel.SConstruct.py:

```
#   author: "Finnian Reilly"
#   copyright: "Copyright (c) 2001-2012 Finnian Reilly"
#   contact: "finnian at eiffel hyphen loop dot com"
#   license: "MIT license (See: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)"
#   date: "3 June 2010"
#   revision: "0.2"

import os, sys

from os import path

from eiffel_loop.eiffel import project
from eiffel_loop.scons import eiffel

from eiffel_loop.eiffel.ecf import EIFFEL_CONFIG_FILE
from eiffel_loop.eiffel.ecf import FREEZE_BUILD
from eiffel_loop.eiffel.ecf import C_CODE_TAR_BUILD
from eiffel_loop.eiffel.ecf import FINALIZED_BUILD

from SCons.Script import *

# SCRIPT START
arguments = Variables()
arguments.Add (EnumVariable('cpu', 'Set target cpu for compiler', 'x64', allowed_values=('x64', 'x86')))

arguments.Add (
    EnumVariable('action', 'Set build action', 'finalize',
        allowed_values=(
            Split ("freeze finalize finalize_and_test finalize_and_install install_resources make_installers")
        )
    )
)
arguments.Add (BoolVariable ('compile_eiffel', 'Compile Eiffel source (no implies C compile only)', 'yes'))
arguments.Add (BoolVariable ('install', 'Set to \'yes\' to install finalized release', 'no'))
arguments.Add (PathVariable ('project', 'Path to Eiffel configuration file', 'default.ecf'))

#arguments.Add (
#   ListVariable (
#       'MSC_options', 'Visual Studio setenv.cmd options', '', Split ("/Debug /Release /x86 /x64 /ia64 /vista /xp /2003 /2008 /win7")
#   )
#)

env = Environment (variables = arguments)

Help (arguments.GenerateHelpText (env) + '\nproject: Set to name of Eiffel project configuration file (*.ecf)\n')

if env.GetOption ('help'):
    None

else:
    is_windows_platform = sys.platform == 'win32'
    project_py = project.read_project_py ()

#   MSC_options = env.get ('MSC_options').data
#   if MSC_options:
#       project_py.MSC_options = MSC_options
#       print 'MSC_options:', project_py.MSC_options

    ecf_path = env.get ('project')
    action = env.get ('action')
    compile_eiffel = env.get ('compile_eiffel')

    project_py.set_build_environment (env.get ('cpu'))

    env.Append (ENV = os.environ, ISE_PLATFORM = os.environ ['ISE_PLATFORM'])
    if 'ISE_C_COMPILER' in os.environ:
        env.Append (ISE_C_COMPILER = os.environ ['ISE_C_COMPILER'])

    config = EIFFEL_CONFIG_FILE (ecf_path)

    project_files = [ecf_path, 'project.py']

    if action == 'install_resources':
        build = FREEZE_BUILD (config, project_py)
        build.post_compilation ()
    else:
        if action in ['finalize', 'make_installers']:
            tar_build = C_CODE_TAR_BUILD (config, project_py)
            build = FINALIZED_BUILD (config, project_py)

            if compile_eiffel:
                env.Append (EIFFEL_BUILD = tar_build)
                env.Append (BUILDERS = {'eiffel_compile' : Builder (action = eiffel.compile_eiffel)})
                f_code = env.eiffel_compile (tar_build.target (), project_files)
            else:
                f_code = None

        else:
            build = FREEZE_BUILD (config, project_py)
            f_code = None

        env.Append (C_BUILD = build)
        env.Append (BUILDERS = {'c_compile' : Builder (action = eiffel.compile_C_code)})

        if f_code:
            executable = env.c_compile (build.target (), tar_build.target ())
        else:
            executable = env.c_compile (build.target (), project_files)

        if build.precompile_path:
            env.Append (BUILDERS = {'precomp_copier' : Builder (action = eiffel.copy_precompile)})
            precompile_name = path.basename (build.precompile_path)
            precompile_dir = path.dirname (path.dirname (build.precompile_path))
            precomp_ecf = env.precomp_copier (build.precompile_path, path.join (precompile_dir, precompile_name))
            if f_code:
                Depends (tar_build.target (), build.precompile_path)
            else:
                Depends (executable, build.precompile_path)

        eiffel.check_C_libraries (env, build)
        if len (build.SConscripts) > 0:
            print "\nDepends on External libraries:"
            for script in build.SConscripts:
                print "\t" + script

        SConscript (build.SConscripts, exports='env')

        # only make library a dependency if it doesn't exist or object files are being cleaned out
        lib_dependencies = []
        for lib in build.scons_buildable_libs:
            if env.GetOption ('clean') or not path.exists (lib):
                if not lib in lib_dependencies:
                    lib_dependencies.append (lib)

        Depends (executable, lib_dependencies)

        productions = [executable, precomp_ecf]
        if f_code:
            productions.append (tar_build.target ())

        env.NoClean (productions)
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell SCons about all source code and configuration files? I guess, it does not see what files were changed. An alternative would be to run EiffelStudio compiler every time, it is smart enough to do incremental recompilation in workbench mode, but may be not suitable for building finalized applications.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution: EiffelStudio compiler `ec` detects the changes!

Comment: Good. I'm adding an answer so that you can mark the question as solved.

Comment: Can you paste the output from scons --tree=prune? That will show you all the files SCons is aware of.  Also paste your SConstruct.

Comment: @bdbaddog updated the ticket, nothing in the source folder is tracked!

Comment: Can you include the source for: eiffel_loop.eiffel.SConstruct ?

Comment: @gdbaddog done! Though we are happy with the answer given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *SCons* does not know or see what files have been changed, an alternative is to run *EiffelStudio* compiler every time. It performs quick incremental recompilation in workbench mode, so you are not penalized by waiting for recompilation from scratch.

**Note.** If you are not using graphical environment, projects can be built with a slightly smaller and slightly faster `ecb` version of the compiler (instead of the regular `ec`). But this comes at the cost of incompatibility with the IDE (e.g., in completely non-interactive compilation setups).